# python selenium youtube like button

Tags: python, selenium

So I am trying for over an hour now to make selenium click the youtube like button...
Nothing works on google and I have no idea what to do anymore.
If someone can help me that would be amazing 
(Im kinda new to python)
Thanks!

Comment: Have you try inspecting the xpath of the youtube like button?

Comment: you should post what you have tried and the resulting error

Comment: If you want to click like . You also need to send your youtube account's information.

Comment: Your code trials and the error(if any)?

Answer (score 1):

So following on my comment, you need to inspect the xpath of the youtube like button.

Right click on the like button, press inspect element. It should show a console and in the console the like button path should be highlight. Click on it then click copy xpath.

After that do what you need to do, e.g `like_button_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath of the like button').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Selenium docs: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

The below is tested and working - remember that to like videos, you always need to be logged into your Youtube account.

1) Identify the buttons xPath:

To extract the specific Like button xPath, you can inspect the button through any developer browser tool, right click on it and select Copy xPath:

[image]

Then just copy the xPath **into** here:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("here")
```

2) Log into Youtube and click on the Like button

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
youtube = driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fHt-VVG_hg")
sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='top-level-buttons']/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1]/a")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess it didnt work for me since i thought the xpath was "//*[@id="button"]" (this is what chrome gave me..)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
//yt-animated-icon[contains(@animated-icon-type,"LIKE")]